# AURELIA-CLI : how to use node module 'crypto' with aurelia-cli loader

Tags: cryptography, aurelia

I have an AURELIA application that uses the node module 'crypto'.
It works fine with GULP/JSPM (after 'npm install crypto' and 'jspm install crypto').

Now I want to use aurelia-cli instead of JSPM.
But I didn't succeed to load 'crypto' with the Aurelia-cli.
When building the app with 'au build' I got the error:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '......\src\crypto.js'

I certainly need to reference 'crypto' in aurelia.json file but I don't find what to insert in this file.
Thanks if somebody could provide aurelia.json content for using crypto.